# iPhone: Open view "in and out" by pulling an image/button from the bottom

Tags: iphone

i'm trying to implemente a map view as a "sliding drawer" view from bottom to top. I was hoping to make it possible to "pull" the view in and out as can be seen on plenty of Android applications out there.

However, I haven't seen this on any iPhone apps yet. Of course, there are apps that do this from right/left(facebook app, ...), but I haven't seen this done from the bottom to top yet.

Why is this? And if possible, where should i look for help in implementing this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [this](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ecslidingviewcontroller--2)

Also You can implement this by using some animation code and changing frame of your view.

```
-(void)animateAndHideSidePanel{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView  setAnimationDuration:0.45f];
    [viewSidePanel setFrame:CGRectMake(-viewSidePanel.frame.size.width, 
                                       viewSidePanel.frame.origin.y,
                                       viewSidePanel.frame.size.width,
                                       viewSidePanel.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];  
    isSidePanelShowing = NO;
}



-(void)animateAndShowSidePanel {    
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView  setAnimationDuration:0.45f];
    [viewSidePanel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 
                                       viewSidePanel.frame.origin.y,
                                       viewSidePanel.frame.size.width,
                                       viewSidePanel.frame.size.height)];
        [self.viewSidePanel setHidden:NO];
        [UIView commitAnimations];  
}
```

Where `viewSidePanel` is my view which I want to hide and show on click of a button.You can vary the frame alterations to implement the desired effect. Hope it helps